# How to let parent module to import a child module of the child module in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, module, require

```
Module A
│
└─ Module B (devDependency in Module A's package.json)
   │
   └─ Module C (dependency in Module B's package.json)
```

Module B is what I am developing. But I know that module C would be called in Module A with `require('Module C')`. And the error I am having is `Cannot find module 'Module C'`.

My current solution is ugly which is:

In index.js of Module B

```
exports.Module_C = require('Module_C) || require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/Module_C/index');
```

In Module A

```
require('Module_B').Module_C
```

I am hoping there is better way to do it.

Comment: If module A does a require on module C, then it needs to be a direct dependency of module A and NPM will make it available to module A directly.  The newest NPM keeps dependent modules in a flatter hierarchy so that the same module C can be used from both A and B (though it should be separately listed as a dependent module for both).

Comment: If you're not going to make module C a dependency for module A, then you will have to proxy it's interface through B so that A can get it from B as in `require('Module_B').Module_C`.  Those are your two best options.  Either make it a dependency so NPM will make it available or proxy it.  You could reach into module B's file hierarchy to get to module C from module A, but that is not a recommended way to do things.

Comment: I know that would do it. But the thing is there is Module_D, Module_E, like the Module_C, and I don't want people who is writing Module_A, the user of Module_B, to npm install Module_C/D/E. I want that user could just npm install Module_B, then that is it.

Comment: Well as Norguard said, modules are NOT inherited in node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are not inherited.

If you need the same module in two different places in your system, just require it in two different places.

```
// A.js
var C = require("./modules/c");
var B = require("./modules/b");


// B.js
var C = require("./modules/c");
module.exports = { };

// C.js
module.exports = { };
```

If you need to import subsections of a module, then navigate to the file (or root of the files) that you need.

```
// app.js
var add = require("./lib/helpers/math/add");
```

If you are trying to offer the functionality of multiple modules inside of one module, then what you're looking for is a service, which you will create an API for, to abstract what you want the end user to be able to do, from all of the places you need to touch, in order to do it.

Even if that service / library is basically just extending other interfaces onto its own interface.